# How can i validate for Creation of Lead in my Custom Module in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have my custom module. When i create a new lead, it is validation for **Subject** (field name="name"), if that field is not filled we cannot create a Lead. But I want to create the Lead only if I enter either of Email or Phone number.

How can I check whether that those fields are empty or not before creating the Lead and inform user to enter either Email or Phone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the Fields are **required True**, than we must give value for the Fields. If we forget to
 set value, the **Notification** comes like that filed is not set and mark with Red Rectangle.

- Now Without Create Lead with No given Subject. Than You Need to change the Data Structure of Table. Search for **name** field and remove **required=True**, And Start server with **-u module_name -d database_name**
- Now Create a Lead if Only Email or Phone Number has value. Need to below code of button Click Method. You can add attribute required=1 for Email and Phone. If the User not set the value than it's give notification like **Subject** For Example

  ```
  email = vals.get('email_from')
  phone = vals.get('phone')

  if not email:
      raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('Please Enter Email.'))
  elif not phone:
      raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('Please Enter Phone Number.'))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your .xml file:

```
<field name="email" attrs="{'required': [('phone','=', False)]}"/>
<field name="phone" attrs="{'required': [('email','=', False)]}"/>
```

Hope this will help you